# How to Select img tags title or alt withing td using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am having the below table with five columns. out of five columns column#5 have image icon which changes randomly with back-end data.Image don't have id or class which is static.

[image]

CSS as below:

[image]

With below code I able to get column#4 text.

```
var temp = driverIE.FindElement
(By.XPath("//td[@class ='af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111'][4]"))
                    .GetAttribute("innerText");
```

I tried to get image tags `alt` or `title` with below code but it's returning null.

```
var temp = driverIE.FindElement
(By.XPath("//td[@class ='af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111'][5]/img"))
                    .GetAttribute("alt");
```

I am trying to get `title` or `alt` value to a temporary variable. Further I have to divert control to different method as per value.

Comment: When you test the XPath locator in Chrome Developer tools is it selecting the image element?

Comment: @AntonAngelov No!, I am only able to locate `//td[@class ='af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111'][5]`. I'm unable to locate `img` in that `td`

Comment: Hello! Please include the html in the question instead of just as an image. From the guide: ["also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @AntonAngelov got the solution. Added extra `/` and I got what I wanted.

Comment: @mrfreester will do that going further. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the people who may face this issue, adding the solution.

**Before:**

```
var temp = driverIE.FindElement
(By.XPath("//td[@class ='af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111'][5]/img"))
                    .GetAttribute("alt");
```

**After:**

```
var temp = driverIE.FindElement
(By.XPath("//td[@class ='af_column_cell-text OraTableBorder1111'][5]//img"))
                    .GetAttribute("alt");
```

Comment: considering provided piece of `HTML` this doesn't seem to be a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Chrome developer tools once again. Use the arrow to find your element, use the right click context menu go to Copy XPath.

Comment: Thanks @AntonAngelov got the solution. Added extra `/` and I got what I wanted.